# pass value as array/collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var addNew = $('#divListBox').find(':checked')
                     .map(function() {
                         return $(this).val();
                     }).get();
```

I want to know if there's a way to get all the value that's checked and put them in a collection so I can send it to my controller?

Comment: Your code seems to be fine, what are you expecting?

Comment: What's a "collection", by your definition?

Comment: Ya, do you mean that you want a collection to be passed into your server side handler? OR some sort of JavaScript controller?

Comment: @ Everyone -- I think I got what I was looking for. I guess I was just thinking way too much. So what I did was with the code sample provided above, I was able to get the ids: "1,2,3,etc." I pass that variable "addNew" as a parameter to serverside where I create another variable "colAddNew = addNew.Split(',')" to put it in a collection. I then iterate through and was able to get to where I want to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this...

```
var v_coll=[];
$('#divListBox').find(':checked').each(function(){
   v_coll.push($(this).val);
});
```